# Webtest - missing dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, dll, web-testing

When I creating webtests I want to add "Web Test Plug-in" I get message box with information that one of my nuget library is missing.

Whole my solution is compilable and this "missing" library exists as entry in csproj and config files. After compilation of test project this library is inside "bIn" folder. I check under dotPeek version, publicToken etc is correct.

My question is where webtest project look for this library?

Answer (score 0):

**If the webtests is missing a dependency:**

Right click solution > manage nuget packages for solution > click manage on the package in question, then select your webtests project > ok.

**If the webtests has a broken link to a dll :**

Look at the references, and see if there are any yellow triangles, and where they point to. If that is the case, delete that reference and re-attach.

Comment: @Jacek try doing a clean & rebuild, and see if the library remains in the bin folder

Comment: yes, I did it. I use also git clean -xdf to have clean workspace. And still i doesn't work

Comment: @Jacek best thing to do is, post the full error, and the contents of your csproj and config files.

Comment: At this moment I'm in home, I not have access to this code. I can post this data on Monday